# Consider the system of equations $ax +by = 0$, $cx + dy = 0$ where $a,b,c,d \in$ {0,1}

Tags: probability

The question given is

> Consider the system of equations $ax +by = 0$, $cx + dy = 0$ where
> $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1\}.$ Find the probability that the system of equation
> has a unique solution

The solution for this question provided considers the total number of cases to be 16. That means it consider 2 options for each variable and so the total number of cases would be $2^4 = 16$. My doubt however is that, how is it possible than in $ax + by = 0$ both $a$ and $b$ can be taken as zero. Then it doesn't make sense since its no longer a valid equation. Hence I did this question by calculating the total cases where atleast one of $a,b$ and $c,d$ are 1. Which method is correct and why?

Comment: $0=0$ is certainly a valid equation.  It's always true, so it doesn't have a unique solution (even when combined with a second equation of the form $cx+dy=0$).

Comment: Hint: You can't have $a,c$ both $= 0$, since that would leave $x$ totally unconstrained.  In such a situation, a constraint violation would have to occur, regardless of whether the constraint on $y$ is *solvable*.

Comment: Hint: re previous comment, similar consideration outlaws $a,b$ both $= 0.$

Comment: If $a=b=0$, the first equation $0x+0y=0$ is true for all values of $x,y$. It is a valid equation. What is the issue?

Comment: $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is always a solution, so you want it to be the only solution.

Comment: The system has a unique solution iff its determinant is nonzero.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri $a = b = 0$ is equivalent to saying that the first equation is leaving $x,y$ **totally unconstrained**.  Since the question is focusing on a **unique** solution for $x,y$, and since a single equation $cx + dy = 0$ is insufficient to generate a unique solution, no **unique** solution will ever be generated when $a,b = 0$.

Comment: @user2661923 Precisely why $a=b=0$ will be counted in the cases which do not generate unique solution. OP has removed this from the $16$ total possibilities.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Because when $a = b = 0$, the equation $ax + by = 0$ will be satisfied for **any** $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2}.$  This means that when $a = b = 0$, the only constraint on $(x,y)$ is $cx + dy = 0$.  It is impossible for there to be only 1 unique solution to the single constraint $cx + dy = 0$.  The issue is what values for $(a,b,c,d)$ yield exactly 1 solution in $(x,y)$, where $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1\}.$  Actually, I think that the recent comment of Yves Daoust clarifies the situation very nicely.

Comment: @user2661923 You are misunderstanding the question. The questioner has said that the official solution considers **total** $16$ cases that may generate unique/non-unique solutions, out of which the number of cases that yield a unique solution have to be determined. But the questioner is inclined to not consider $a=b=0$ among those $16$ **total** cases as he thinks that it doesn't represent a valid equation. In short, if the total number of cases that generate unique solution is $x$, instead of reporting the answer as $x/16$, the OP is inclined to report $x/(16-7)$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri "Find the probability that the system of equation has a unique solution": I have to disagree with your comment because I can only interpret this quoted excerpt in 1 way.  That is, you examine each of the $(16)$ possible values of $(a,b,c,d)$ and determine which of these values generates a unique solution.  For example, $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,c,d)$ will never generate a unique solution, regardless of whether $c = 0 ~\text{or} ~1$ and regardless of whether $d = 0 ~\text{or} ~1.$  Perhaps we should agree to disagree on how to interpret the excerpt that I quoted.

Comment: @user2661923 I think the meaning will be clearer if you interpret it along with the body of the question, instead of just the first line. The second last line ("Hence I did this question by calculating the total cases where atleast one of a,b and c,d are 1") makes it pretty clear what the OP is trying to convey, according to me. :)

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Consider the problem's background.  The excerpt that I quoted is probably the original wording of the problem.  Assuming so, if the OP's intent is something else, then the OP has mis-interpreted the problem.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri is correct in his interpretation. It's possibly my fault that I couldn't convey what I wanted to ask. I understand the condition for unique solutions but was not sure whether for total cases considering all the variables to be 0 could be an option as that didn't seem logical for me to even include that in the total cases. But looks like 
 that doesn't really matter and the variables can assume those values simultaneously.

Comment: To the OP: Are you saying that the excerpt that I quoted is not the original wording of the problem?  This is a critical issue.  If it isn't the original wording, then what is the problem's original wording?  Alternatively, if the quoted excerpt is the problem's original wording, does it seem reasonable to you that you have mis-interpreted the problem?

Comment: @user2661923 It is in the original wording of the problem, but calculating the probability requires me to find the favorable cases and the total cases in sample space. So I had problem's in the second part

Comment: Given your response, a favorable case is just what Yves Daoust and I have indicated is a favorable case.  This implies that you have mis-interpreted the problem.  For example, $a = 0 = b$ does result in a valid equation.  It is simply that this valid equation can not lead to a unique solution.